# Calendar control in DatePicker cutting off HeaderButton?

Tags: wpf, xaml

My calendar on my DatePicker is cutting off the CalendarHeaderButton so it is unreadable. I've tried removing my XAML style and using the standard Calendar and the issue is still there. Does anybody know how to rectify this? Sorry if this is a duplicate, I spent quite a while searching!

[image: Calendar Header Missing]

Here is my Xaml so far:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type Calendar}" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Back75}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Text100}"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                    <!-- Wrapping in ViewBox will enlarge calendar of that size.-->
                    <Viewbox Height="200"
                         Width="200">
                        <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem"
                                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of this issue. It turns out that 'HeaderButton' uses 'Button'. I had a default style on 'button' which set the height to '20' and it needed to be '25'. I manually changed this in a 'CalendarItem' style which hard-codes the height of the button to 25.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your style and it works fine by itself, it must come from somewhere else. Have you tried using your style in a new project with just a Calendar in the main window? 
You should post the minimal code that causes your problem if you want further help. 
On a side note, i'm wondering why you're wrapping your CalendarItem in a ViewBox in the style, instead of wrapping your Calendar in a ViewBox wherever you use it.
 And why you're setting the size of your ViewBox as hard-coded 200-200.

Comment: I am wrapping my CalendarItem in a viewbox in the style because this is in a resource dictionary and I want everything to be uniform - Why would this be an issue?

What is the issue of hard-coding the size of the viewbox? That is the reason I'm using a viewbox - To scale the size of the Date/time picker.

Comment: I'm not saying using a style in a resource dictionary is an issue, I think that is a good thing. What I'm saying is that your style is not the issue.
Here's what I get when I try a minimal window containing just a grid then a callendar using your style : [calendar screen](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/442445calendarscreen.png). I think yout problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There is just understanding issue. DatePicker is conflicting with button property "Height" which you have configured in your application.